# how to specify start time of mid-roll ad in VAST 3.0

Tags: vast

I'm trying to specify the start time of mid-roll ad in vast 3.0. I referred to the 3.0 spec but could not find anything about it. I was wondering if someone has already done that. 
thanks
~b

Answer (score 2):

Its not in scope of VAST to define the video player playlist or location of ads (pre/mid/post roll). Usually its controlled by the "owner" of the player. But there is also VMAP specification from IAB.

To quote the 3.0 standard (page 62):

> VAST can supply the ads but cannot specify where in the content the ads should play or which ads and how many should play in a specified ad spot.
>   Using VMAP ad breaks can be defined at specific times within the content timeline. Ad breaks can specify which type of ads and how many can play in an ad break.

Comment: thanks for the reply. As a followup question are there any vast 3.0 compliant players to test the generated vast xml. The schema is available for testing the compliance but I am looking. I found players for testing vast 2.0 but not 3.0.

Comment: Yeah, I've not seen any 3.0 inspectors. There a js vast player that claims to support vast 3.0 and they have a preview http://www.jsvast.com/preview/  That being said, vast 2.0 and vast 3.0 should be compatible with each other, and most inspectors / players are relaxed about the schema.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this inspector supports vast 3.0 (alteast Adpods)  https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/vastinspector_dual